# Convert a get;set string DateEntered from yyyy-MM-dd to MM-dd-yyyy in C#?

Tags: c#, date, datetime, time

In one .cs file I have the following:

```
public string DateEntered { get; set; }
```

In another .cs file then I have another string to grab a certain date.

```
public string HighestDate
    {
      get
        {
           ...
           return d.DateEntered;
        }
    }
```

Wondering how to convert the output from yyyy-MM-dd to MM-dd-yyyy? The scope in which it is used is as follows:

```
data.HighestDate
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Another part of the code that I think is integral:

```
var s = this...(i => i.DateEntered == DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"));
```

However this only changes certain instances of the date format.

Comment: Why not saving both property as `DateTime` instead of `string`? You should always choose the _proper_ type of your properties. Then you can format them (with generally `.ToString()`) as a _textual_ reprsentation.

Comment: You should be saving the underlying date as a `DateTime` variable, not a string.  Then you can show your string in the UI in whatever format you wish.

Comment: Sorry I added an edit where I think it's set to DateTime.

Answer (score 2):

You should always store dates as `DateTime` variables:

```
public DateTime DateEntered { get; set; }
```

Then you can render the date however you like in your consumer application (UI):

```
public string HighestDate
{
  get
    {
       ...
       return d.DateEntered.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry... removed it! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you save them both as `DateTime`, then you can use `data.HighestDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")`. Otherwise, you could use:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(data.HighestDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
```

Although you should still try to modify your code to save them as `DateTime` objects, this is the right-proper way to do it. (And saves memory space.)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx

Quick Googling would have net you your result.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime parsedDate;
if (DateTime.TryParse(data.HighestDate, out parsedDate))
{
    var reformatted = parsedDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
}
```

Comment: There is no guarantee to parse `data.HighestDate` without any `IFormatProvider`. And these properties types should be `DateTime` because their names ends with `..Date`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I recommend using a DateTime to store the value and turn it into a string at the last possible moment.

Secondly, use DateTime.ParseExact to read a particular format from a string and use ToString("some format") to format a DateTime to a string